# Identifying if object already exists in CreateView

Tags: django, django-views

Is there a way of determining if an object exists in the database. If it does, an "object already exists" is returned. Otherwise, a new object is created.

Comment: Not related, but I still prefer to use `CreateView` and `UpdateView` separately, maybe extract the common part into a base class.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question in order to get the desired answer.

Comment: https://chriskief.com/2015/01/19/create-or-update-with-a-django-modelform/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the solution I implemented had to go to the `ModelForm`:

```
class LabelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Label
        fields = ('name',)

    def clean(self):
        if Label.objects.filter(name=self.cleaned_data['name'].lower()).exists()
            raise forms.ValidationError('Label exists!')

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `get_or_create` method? With this, you will also see, whether or not the object has been newly created. If not, you return your "object already exists".

You should probably do this in your override of the `post(request, *args, **kwargs)` method within your view.

See [the docs for futher information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)